# Is it possibility to alert the users as soon as the data is changed by another user (or process) on Oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I have an Oracle form with many database data-blocks on it. Sometimes, users open the form and start entering the data. Meanwhile, a process is automatically run and updates the values in the tables. In some cases another user on another form changes the data and commits his changes.

These changes are not visible to the users which have the form opened. When they press "save" button, they would receive the message which says the data has been changed by another user and they have to refresh the data (due to using the dalyed locking mode).

I just wonder if we have the possibility to alert the users as soon as the data is changed by another user (or process).

Our process has the first priority, therefore, we don't want to lock the row as soon as the first user started to work on it.

Does anyone have a novel idea?!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to place a lock on the record so someone cannot have the _ability_ to edit a record when someone else is. Get clever and tell them who and when when they try.

Comment: Is Oracle Form able to subscribe to an [Oracle Advanced Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm) ? If it is, maybe you should be able to build something with a trigger (or Oracle Stream?) pushing a change notification on the queue?

Comment: mmmmmpie, already I have a lock on the record, but this cause our processes which have the hieghest priority to hang.

Comment: Sylvain Leroux, there is no interface with Oracle Forms, thanks!

Comment: All you need is the Continuous Query Notification feature. Look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_cqn.htm#BDCGGACA

Comment: Cyryl1972, this sounds interesting! I wanna read a little bit about this.

Comment: Hang on, Oracle Forms' default behaviour should be to automatically request locks on any row as soon as the user starts to edit it. If the rows are being updated by other processes, something may be wrong with your automatic locking behaviour.

Comment: Jeffrey, I have changed the locking mode as I explained before, that is what I did intentionally :-)

Comment: Cyryl1972, Could I use Continious Query Notification on Oracle Forms? I cannot find any example or anything which says how could I impelement it on Forms Builder!